# How to obtain the dictionary of features and tensors of a tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Given the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'feat_binomial': [5, 1, 7, 4, 6],
    'feat_normal': [5.001512, 5.346654, -0.480363,4.821558,-2.080958],
    'feat_ordinal': ['low', 'low', 'low','low','low'],
    'feat_string': ['a', 'b', 'b','b','b'],
})

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df))
```

I would like to get the dictionary of features and tensors, which one would have it when applying the `map` function to the dataset. Here it can be seen printed:

```
def print_input_dict(input_dict):
    features_tensors = dict(input_dict)
    print(features_tensors)
    return features_tensors

dataset.map(print_input_dict)
```

```
{'feat_binomial': <tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=() dtype=int32>,
 'feat_normal': <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=() dtype=float64>,
 'feat_ordinal': <tf.Tensor 'args_2:0' shape=() dtype=string>,
 'feat_string': <tf.Tensor 'args_3:0' shape=() dtype=string>}
```

In order to get this dictionary I have managed to do the following:

```
def _extract_labels(input_dict):
    global features_tensors
    features_tensors = dict(input_dict)
    return features_tensors

dataset.map(print_input_dict)
```

so that it is stored in a global variable which I can later access, but this does not feel like the correct way of doing it. Is there any other way of getting this dictionary?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try using iterator,

```py
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
feature_dict = iterator.get_next() # Returns Dictionary of features
```